# MongoDB: Create an Exact Match field

Tags: regex, mongodb, match, querying

I'm trying order some data, and want to have the exact match as first results and then the rest.

I tried with this $eq in $project, but it seems that something won't work.

Is it possible to do something similar?

```
db.getCollection('words').aggregate([
    { $match: { "kanji.text": /^彼/ } },
    { $project: { 
        "kanji": 1,
        "kana": 1,
        "sense":1,
        "exact": { 
           $eq : [ "$kanji.0.text", "彼" ]
        }
      }
    },
    { $sort: {"exact": 1} }
])
```

Document Structure:

[image: Document Structure]

**EDIT: I have found a bad workaround**

```
db.getCollection('words').aggregate([
    { $match: { "kanji.text": /^彼/ } },
    { $limit : 10 },
    { $addFields: {
        exact: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$kanji.text',
                cond: {
                    $eq: ['$$this', "彼"]
                }
            }
        }
    }},
    { $project: { 
        "kanji": 1,
        "kana": 1,
        "sense":1,
        "exact": 1
      }
    },
    { $sort: {"exact.0": -1} }
])
```

Comment: Query seems write to me. Check collation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/

Comment: I tried with a simple query, but nothing..

$project: {
        "hello": "world",
        "exact": { $eq: ["$hello", "world"] }}